# Python list generation from file, and return specific value from source match

Tags: python

I am trying to build a script in python which will read the file contains list of Policy-maps and generate a list. need to refer to another source for a specific policy-map and return only that values from current list.

i have read the file using the readlines() and generated a list. unable to combine the indexes as follows.

```
['policy-map mohideen1\n', ' class class-default\n', '  service-policy mohideen_child\n', '  police rate 80000000 bps burst 1250000 bytes peak-burst 1250000 bytes \n', '   conform-action transmit\n', '   exceed-action drop\n', '  !\n', ' !\n', ' end-policy-map\n', '!\n', 'policy-map mohideen2\n', ' class class-default\n', '  service-policy mohideen2_child\n', '  police rate 100000000 bps burst 1562500 bytes peak-burst 1562500 bytes \n', '   conform-action transmit\n', '   exceed-action drop\n', '  !\n', ' !\n', ' end-policy-map\n', '!\n', '\n']
```

Expected output should be as follows:
which should combine all indexes which follows \n' , and the second index should after that, ideally i need to have 2 index in this list.

Post list generation as expected, i have a policy-list in notepad, need to iterate through that and if matches found in existing new list, then the specific index should be returned.

```
with open('ICR_input.txt' , 'r') as file_object:
    full = file_object.readlines()
    print (full)
    s = full.split('end-policy-map')
    print(s)
```

Output

```
SOURCE = ['a\n' , 'b\n',  '!\n', 'c\n' , 'd\n' ,'!\n']
```

to be modified as follows

```
SOURCE1 =  ['a\n b\n', 'c\n d\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to separate your text by "!\n"?

You might want to use .read() instead of .readlines() in order to get a string at first. Then, use split("!\n") to create the desired list.

I took the liberty of writing a function for you:

```
def readFile(filename):
    F=open(filename,"r")
    s=F.read()
    F.close()
    return s.split("!\n")
```

Comment: Thanks Dorijan. It worked.. I would like to sincerely thank you for your prompt support.

Comment: @MohideenPitchai No problem. Good luck with your program!